# IllegalStateException: Cannot set the device owner if the device is already set-up

Tags: android, android-source, mdm

I'm trying to active the device owner of my system application using hidden API 
from `DevicePolicyManager` method `dpm.setDeviceOwner(cmpName)`. This method is throwing illegalStateException. I also tried 
`Settings.Global.putInt(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Global.DEVICE_PROVISIONED, 0);` and 
`Settings.Secure.putInt(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.USER_SETUP_COMPLETE, 0);`. But android studio is still throwing an error.

**Note** : I have both permission in manifest `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS" />` and `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_PROFILE_AND_DEVICE_OWNERS" />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I received that error when calling `dpm.setProfileOwner` before `dpm.setActiveAdmin`; after all, a profile owner must first be an active admin. However, you'll quickly find that, even if you issue the appropriate sequence of commands you'll then receive the error: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to set non-default profile owner post-setup`.

If you check your logcat, though, I suspect you'll also find a warning similar to one I received: `avc: denied { write } for name="com.myorg.mapp-0AMhJFjDAJrJ-KmxrLiEPA==" dev="dm-3" ino=3558 scontext=u:r:system_app:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:apk_data_file:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0`

This message is the key... The problem is that selinux rules prevent the apk from making changes directly to the /data/system directory, which is where the xml files (device_owner_2.xml and device_policies.xml) that define profile ownership are located.

In short, you're out of luck. You have a few workaround options:

- Run the `dpm set-profile-owner` command from within a rooted shell. Since it is run as root this will bypass selinux rules. This is a great option for quick tests
- Grant your application root access to execute the command directly. This is a good option if you know your devices will be rooted and don't want to have to remember the command.
- Compile your ROM with the relevant access xml files already baked-in.

If you're building a system app (which you must be with those permissions), you're almost certainly rooted or building a ROM, so one of the above options should work.

Comment: Although it is late, but your answer is very helpful. We used 3rd option to achieve our goal. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered a very similar problem using Android Q. I know it's been answered already, but I found another thing that I did that worked, based on DPM implementation in this [link](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/1c14fbc/cmds/dpm/src/com/android/commands/dpm/Dpm.java). I implemented a platform priv-app with this method:

```
private void setDeviceOwnerAndAdmin() {
    int mUserId = UserHandle.USER_SYSTEM;
    try {
        //Get the Stub implementation for device policy service
        IDevicePolicyManager mDevicePolicyManager = IDevicePolicyManager.Stub.asInterface(
                ServiceManager.getService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE));

        //Get the admin component from DeviceAdmin class
        ComponentName component = new ComponentName(mContext, DeviceAdmin.class);

        //Set active system admin
        mDevicePolicyManager.setActiveAdmin(component, true /*refreshing*/, mUserId);

        //Set the device owner for this component
        if (!mDevicePolicyManager.setDeviceOwner(component, "OwnerName", mUserId)) {
            throw new RuntimeException(
                    "Can't set package " + component + " as device owner.");
        }
        //Set provisioning state
        mDevicePolicyManager.setUserProvisioningState(
                DevicePolicyManager.STATE_USER_SETUP_FINALIZED, mUserId);
    } catch (Exception e) {
       Log.e(TAG, "Error at setting Owner and Admin", e);
    }

}
```

Then the exception occured with the message

> Cannot set the device owner if the device is already set-up

I then added `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS" />` and `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_PROFILE_AND_DEVICE_OWNERS" />` to the Manifest.

Also, added the priv-app package to `/frameworks/base/data/etc/privapp-permissions-platform.xml` with the right permissions.

After all that, I still had the same exception message, until I figured out that the `frameworks/base/packages/SettingsProvider/res/values/defaults.xml` had the value `<bool name="def_user_setup_complete">true</bool>`. That was preventing me from adding a device owner, so I changed this value to `false` and it worked.